Vba code take 10 minutes to load how to fix this
I am fairly new to vba code and I am having trouble figuring out two things. The first issue is the amount of load time it takes my code to work. It takes 10+ minutes to run my code. I don't know what to do to speed this up. The second issue is when calling other codes it doesn't work properly, it doesn't copy the individual into the winner spreadsheet, but when I press button individual everything works. If I could get help optimizing this code that would be great or any ideas to try to fix my code
Sub Access_Tabel()
'
' Access_Tabel Macro
'


'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Access Table").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Information Sheet Hidden").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Information Sheet Hidden").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Information_Hidden_Sheet").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5 _
        , Criteria1:=Array("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "19", "2", "20", _
        "21", "22", "27", "3", "31", "4", "5", "54", "6", "7", "8", "9", "94"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub Names_Repeated()
'
' Names_Repeated Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Names Repeated").Select
    Sheets("Information Sheet Hidden").Visible = True
    Range("E3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Names Repeated").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Information Sheet Hidden").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Names Repeated").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Information Sheet Hidden").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Names Repeated").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Information Sheet Hidden").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub Raffel_Table_Both()
'
' Raffel_Table_Both Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Names Repeated").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Raffel Table Hidden").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Raffel Table Hidden").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Raffel Table Hidden").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Raffel Table Query Hidden2").Select
    Range("Table5_2[Raffel Entires]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table5").Refresh
    Sheets("Raffel Table Query Hidden2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub Winner_Copied()
'
' Winner_Copied Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Winners Hidden").Select
    Sheets("Raffel Table Query Hidden2").Visible = True
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Winners Hidden").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Raffel Table Query Hidden2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Winners Hidden").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Raffel Table Query Hidden2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Raffel Table Query Hidden2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
End Sub

Sub CallerMacro()

Call Access_Tabel
Call Names_Repeated
Call Raffel_Table_Both
Call Winner_Copied

End Sub


A good start would be avoiding Select.

Nine of those 10 minutes is spent on doing all the bouncing around you're doing with the overuse of .Select. You should avoid using it like the plague.

I see a lot going on but very little actually happening. Go here, select this cell, select all the cells to the bottom, copy those cells, now go to this sheet, select this cell, paste those other cells here. You can very simply define the range as a variable, copy it, and put the destination on another variable-name.

How do I go about not using select. When these are dynamic tables that will add or subtract rows based on employee roster and participation I felt like select was the way to go based of it covers the entire table. Fairly new to VBA this was a small project that I undertook that I thought would be easy but the crashing and 10 minute load times has made this into a nightmare

You can simply say Dim rng as Range at the top, then later on Set rng = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Access Table").Range("A2") for example and you can use rng.copy  instead of rng.select & selection.copy as the link BigBen shared explains in detail. But obviously this would need to be adjusted to account for the entire range you're trying to copy not just A2. But the idea is you define what the rng is and then you can use rng (or whatever variable) instead of selecting the cells. The computer can just put a value in a cell, there's no need for the computer to 'click' on that cell first.

How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

I appreciate everyone quick response. I will look into getting rid of select by using dim range. Thanks!

I think the following line takes a lot of time. ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table5").Refresh

Getting rid of .Select is definitely a good thing - and should always be recommended to make the code more robust and tidier, but let's not go overboard here - there are no loops involved in this code so it might shave a couple of seconds off the overall time, nothing more. If the code is taking 10 minutes then it's either the autofilter dealing with masses of rows, or more likely just the connection refresh. Also, depending on the workbook's set up, turning off calculations might help.
